# Finding final configuration after flipping bits

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-mathematics

You have a thousand bits, all 0s (zeros). We define an operation as flipping all bits between the a-th bit and the b-th bit. What is the fastest way to find the final configuration after a thousand operations?

Comment: I assume a and b included?

Comment: yes, both included

Answer (score 0):

Count all occurrences of the values (a,b). Scan the values occurrences, from least to most where the pattern starts with 0 bits. With the first odd count changes values to 1. At the next odd value change to 0. And so on every odd count changes the value of the string following it.

Comment: If we had (1,3), (5,6), and (1,4), we would get 00011100 (assuming 8 bits). Are you saying we should expand (1,4) to 1,2,3,4 and then count each value's occurrences? Or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Between odd and even counts of the histogram you have values 1.